# "to_tsquery" on tsvector yields different results when using "simple" and "english"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I've been enlisted to help on a project and I'm diving back into PostgreSQL after not working with it for several years. Lack of use aside, I've never run into using tsvector fields before and now find myself facing a bug based on them. I read the documentation on the field type and it's purpose, but I'm having a hard time digging up documentation on how 'simple' differs from 'english' as the first parameter to to_tsquery()

Example

```
> SELECT to_tsvector('mortgag') @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'mortgage')
?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)

> SELECT to_tsvector('mortgag') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'mortgage')
?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

I would think they should both return true, but obviously the first does not - why?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The FTS utilizes [dictionaries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html) to normalize the text:

> **12.6. Dictionaries**
>
> Dictionaries are used to eliminate words that should not be considered in a search (*stop words*), and to *normalize* words so that different derived forms of the same word will match. A successfully normalized word is called a *lexeme*.

So dictionaries are used to throw out things that are too common or meaningless to consider in a search (*stop words*) and to normalize everything else so *city* and *cities*, for example, will match even though they're different words.

Let us look at some output from [`ts_debug`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-debugging.html#TEXTSEARCH-CONFIGURATION-TESTING) and see what's going on with the dictionaries:

```
=> select * from ts_debug('english', 'mortgage');
   alias   |   description   |  token   |  dictionaries  |  dictionary  |  lexemes  
-----------+-----------------+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | mortgage | {english_stem} | english_stem | {mortgag}

=> select * from ts_debug('simple', 'mortgage');
   alias   |   description   |  token   | dictionaries | dictionary |  lexemes   
-----------+-----------------+----------+--------------+------------+------------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | mortgage | {simple}     | simple     | {mortgage}
```

Notice that `simple` uses the `simple` dictionary whereas `english` uses the `english_stem` dictionary.

The [`simple` dictionary](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SIMPLE-DICTIONARY):

> operates by converting the input token to lower case and checking it against a file of stop words. If it is found in the file then an empty array is returned, causing the token to be discarded. If not, the lower-cased form of the word is returned as the normalized lexeme.

The `simple` dictionary just throws out stop words, downcases, and that's about it. We can see its simplicity ourselves:

```
=> select to_tsquery('simple', 'Mortgage'), to_tsquery('simple', 'Mortgages');
 to_tsquery | to_tsquery  
------------+-------------
 'mortgage' | 'mortgages'
```

The `simple` dictionary is too simple to even handle simple plurals.

So what is this `english_stem` dictionary all about? The "stem" suffix is a give away: this dictionary applies a stemming algorithm to words to convert (for example) *city* and *cities* to the same thing. From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SNOWBALL-DICTIONARY):

> **12.6.6. Snowball Dictionary**
>
> The Snowball dictionary template is based on a project by Martin Porter, inventor of the popular Porter's stemming algorithm for the English language. [...] Each algorithm understands how to reduce common variant forms of words to a base, or stem, spelling within its language.

And just below that we see the `english_stem` dictionary:

> ```
> CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY english_stem (
>     TEMPLATE = snowball,
>     Language = english,
>     StopWords = english
> );
> ```

So the `english_stem` dictionary stems words and we can see that happen:

```
=> select to_tsquery('english', 'Mortgage'), to_tsquery('english', 'Mortgages');
 to_tsquery | to_tsquery 
------------+------------
 'mortgag'  | 'mortgag'
```

---

**Executive Summary**: `'simple'` implies simple minded literal matching, `'english'` applies stemming to (hopefully) produce better matching. The stemming turns *mortgage* into *mortgag* and that gives you your match.

Comment: Fantastic! That's exactly what I was looking for - I'll have to spend some more time in the manual. Thank you!

Comment: @mu is too short Have you run into an issue with postgresql 9.6.1 where non-roman characters, such as `你` in `to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery('你')` would be unable to find a string containing `你` in `你好嗎`?

Comment: @Growler Not yet, sound like a good topic for a new question.